# PHP arabic character encoding issue

Tags: php, utf-8, arabic

I am getting one arabic site meta keywords using get_meta_tags. It gives keywords like

> ÇÖÝ ãæÞÚß ,ÇÚáÇã Ïæá ÇáÚÇáã ,ÇäÇÔíÏ ÇÓáÇãíÉ ,ÇáÈË ÇáãÈÇÔÑ ,ÊÍæíá ÇáÚãáÇÊ,ÊáÝÒíæä ãÈÇÔÑ ,ÌÇÝÇ ÓßÑÈÊ,ÍÇáÉ ÇáØÞÓ

Now I want to convert this into arabic letters and need to pass it as API parameter .

How to convert this letters into arabic characters?

If I want to display it into browser means I have solutions using below functions or header.

1. `mb_convert_encode($keywords,'HTML-ENTITIES','UTF-8');`
2. `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`

But I need to pass these keywords as arabic into an API parameter. So need to convert this into arabic characters, please help me.

Comment: Why someone poll down vote?  Please comment reason and do down vote.

Comment: If that one doesn't help, then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Comment: No, I have tried above links already but no luck.